# create objects with variable name passed from for loop

Tags: python, dataframe

My code is

```
import pandas as pd
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
data = {'Symbols':  ['ADANIPORTS.NS','ASIANPAINT.NS','AXISBANK.NS','BAJAJ-AUTO.NS','BAJAJFINSV.NS','BAJFINANCE.NS','BHARTIARTL.NS','TCS.NS']}
nifty10= pd.DataFrame(data)
nifty10['Symbols']
for symbol in nifty10['Symbols']:
      filename = symbol.strip('.NS') #removing .NS and creating a file name so that I can use symbol as filename
      filename = si.get_data(symbol)
```

At the end, I want 4 objects ADANIPORTS, ASIANPAINT, AXISBANK, TCS which contains values returned by si.get_data.

I iterating through symbols and saving each symbol name as filename to use it later.
Then I am passing Symbol through an API, which is returning a dataframe with multiple row and columns.

This output I want to store in a dataframe and want to name the dataframe with filename/symbol which I created in line 2nd last line.

But dataframe on last line is getting saved as **filename** , in nutshell python is not taking filename which in this case would be Adaniport for 1st Asianpaints for 2nd and so on.

How it worked - `vars()[filename] = si.get_data(symbol)`

Comment: Can you show more of the code? I can't tell what is happening from the snippet you've provided.

Comment: The github project hardly has more code and it's unclear both what is in `nifty10.csv`, as well as what you do with `filename` to conclude that it does not contain the correct value. Please provide a complete example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Grismar I have added complete code now. At the end, I want 4 files ADANIPORTS, ASIANPAINT, AXISBANK, TCS which contains values returned by si.get_data.

Comment: Your code still doesn't include any lines that are saving the data, while your question states "But dataframe on last line is getting saved in a file name as filename" - if I run your code (removing the superfluous lines), it runs just fine, retrieving 4 sets of data, which could be printed or saved to file, but your code contains no instructions to save the data.

Comment: for your information and also if you would ask further questions related to this, the dataframe you created is called an object.. not a filename, hence the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

data = {'Symbols':  ['ADANIPORTS.NS','ASIANPAINT.NS','AXISBANK.NS','TCS.NS']}
nifty10= pd.DataFrame(data)

for symbol in nifty10['Symbols']:
    filename = symbol.strip('.NS') 
    vars()[filename] = si.get_data(symbol)
```

But i would recommend keeping them in a dictionary:

```
si_data = {}
for symbol in nifty10['Symbols']:
    filename = symbol.strip('.NS') 
    si_data[filename] = si.get_data(symbol)

si_data['AXISBANK'].head()

    open    high    low close   adjclose    volume  ticker
1998-11-27  3.55    3.55    2.71    3.40    0.416105    21000.0 AXISBANK.NS
1998-11-30  3.25    3.30    3.10    3.21    0.392852    132000.0    AXISBANK.NS
1998-12-01  3.29    3.46    3.22    3.39    0.414881    123500.0    AXISBANK.NS
1998-12-02  3.36    3.44    3.32    3.39    0.414881    75500.0 AXISBANK.NS
1998-12-03  3.44    3.49    3.37    3.39    0.414881    102000.0    AXISBANK.NS
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @StupidWolf